# Getting text to properly format and not wrap in div columns

Tags: css, html, text

I've only been able to find how to do what my text is currently doing. Not prevent it. I would the text to NOT wrap under the image. Yet I cant use a fixed width. The text needs to continue in the same column when the page is resized.

http://jsfiddle.net/avHcA/

```
    <div id="apDiv1">
    <div id="apDiv2">
    <strong>image goes here</strong>
    </div>
    <div id="apDiv3" ><p><strong>Name Goes here in div with main text</strong></p>
    <p>text that I want to stay in its it div and not wrap underneath the 
    image goes here</p></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use percentage widths, like below:

```
#apDiv2 {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 2%;
    width: 38%;
    z-index: 2;
}


#apDiv3 {
    float: left;
    width: 60%;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

Then the text will continue in the same column, even when the window is resized. Just be sure to clear the floats after every #apDiv1. To clear the floats, add something like `<div class="clear"></div>` where the css for the clear class is as follows:

```
.clear { clear: both; }
```

Comment: couldnt I clear it in the apDiv1? since float doesnt apply there and its the parent tag, would it clear them all?

Comment: and separate from that. It still doesnt work properly. Might be because Im trying to implement it in word press (I hate wordpress but its what the dept. chose to work with).

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be using a table. http://jsfiddle.net/YymYF/

I've just copied the divs into their own table cells

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <td>
        <strong><a href="http://climatemaryland.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Casciani_Cheryl.jpg"><img class="alignleft  wp-image-131" style="border: 0px none;" alt="" src="http://climatemaryland.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Casciani_Cheryl.jpg" width="166" /></a></strong>
    </td>
    <td>
        <p><strong>Cheryl Casciani</strong></p>
        <p>Cheryl Casciani is the Director of Neighborhood Sustainability for the
        Baltimore Community Foundation (BCF) where she is responsible for management
        of a range of initiatives aimed at strengthening Baltimore neighborhoods
        and making Baltimore a more sustainable city. Cheryl also serves as the
        Chair of the Baltimore Commission on Sustainability, which was created
        in 2008 and charged with developing and monitoring the implementation of
        Baltimore's Sustainability Plan. She has a Master's in Public and Private
        Management from the Yale School of Management and a Bachelors of Science
        in Economics and Bachelors of Applied Science from the University of Pennsylvania.</p>
    </td>
    </tr>
```

Play around with the table properties to make it look more desirable.